# smooth functions or continuous

Tags: calculus, analysis, numerical-methods

When wesay a function is smooth?
Is there any difference between smooth function and continuous function?
If they are the same, why sometimes we say f is smooth and sometimes f is continuous?

Comment: "smooth" means (at least) "continously differentiable". Sometimes more (even infinite number of) derivatives are required to be continuous.

Comment: @njguliyev, not to nitpick but I think it's relatively common to call Lipschitz continuous ODEs "smooth" - being just smooth enough for existence and uniqueness of solutions.

Comment: A smooth function is one which is everywhere differentiable any number of times and such that it and all its derivatives are $\mathcal{O}(|x|^{-N})$ as $|x|\to\infty$ for all integer $N$. But in (mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothFunction.html) it is defined as a function that has continuous derivatives up to some desired order over some domain. A function can therefore be said to be smooth over a restricted interval such as (a,b) or [a,b]. The number of continuous derivatives necessary for a function to be considered smooth depends on the problem at hand, and may vary from two to infinity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A function being smooth is actually a stronger case than a function being continuous.  For a function to be continuous, the epsilon delta definition of continuity simply needs to hold, so there are no breaks or holes in the function (in the 2-d case).  For a function to be smooth, it has to have continuous derivatives up to a certain order, say k.  We say that function is $C^{k}$ smooth.  An example of a continuous but not smooth function is the absolute value, which is continuous everywhere but not differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 10):

A smooth function is differentiable. Usually infinitely many times.

Comment: ... or at least as often as we need it.

Answer (score 5):

Smooth implies continuous, but not the other way around. There are functions that are continuous everywhere, yet nowhere differentiable.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: Why "Smooth implies continuous" ?

Answer (score 4):

Take $f(x) = x|x|$ it is smooth, and now consider $g(x) = x^3$, this other function is also smooth. However, $g(x)$ is much smoother than $f(x)$ because derivitive of $f(x)$. You can argue that $g(x)$ is infinitely many times smooth. All polynomials belong to $C^\infty$ meaning they are infinitely many times differentiable and are smooth.

However, $h(x) = |x|$ is not smooth, because it has corner.
Please note that all three functions, $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$ are continous.

Here is how $f(x)$ looks like:

[image]

Here is how the derivative of $f(x)$ looks like:

[image]

Here is the second derivate of $f(x)$, as you can see its second derivative is not even continuous:

[image]

Here is the graph of $g(x)$:

[image]

Here is graph of $\frac{d f(x)}{dx} = 3x^2$:

[image]

Here is graph of $\frac{d^2 g(x)}{dx^2} = 6x$:

[image]

Comment: If a function $f$ is smooth, then can I suppose that $f$ is increasing ou decreasing? At least in some interval?

Answer (score 3):

A smooth function can refer to a function that is infinitely differentiable. More generally, it refers to a function having continuous derivatives of up to a certain order specified in the text. This is a much stronger condition than a continuous function which may not even be once differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

A smooth function is a function that has continuous derivatives up to some desired order over some domain. A function can therefore be said to be smooth over a restricted interval such as or . The number of continuous derivatives necessary for a function to be considered smooth depends on the problem at hand, and may vary from two to infinity. A function for which all orders of derivatives are continuous is called a C-infty-function.

Answer (score -2):

Consider a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ say $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, which is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. Usually we do not say it a smooth function.