# $f = \{(x,e^x) \mid x \in \mathbb Z\}$ Is $f$ continuous on its domain?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm fairly new to calculus, so if the question seems ridiculous, my apologies.

We have

> $f = \{(x,e^x) \mid x \in \mathbb Z\}$ Is $f$ continuous on its domain?

So in other words, it is a simple $f(x) = e^x$, with a domain restricted to  integers.

I've heard that when some function is continuous, people refer to it as being "smooth". Based upon this, not very rigorous explanation, I would say that the function defined above is not continuous, because there are a lot of "gaps".

But since this is definitely not an appropriate approach, we would need to refer to the formal definition:

> If $f$ is continuous on its domain, then
>
> 1. $f$ is *defined* at $a$ ($a \in Dom(f))$; and
> 2. $f$ has a *limit* as $x$ approaches $a$; and
> 3. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$.

The first condition is clearly satisfied. But what about second and third?   Are they satisfied? Why/why not?

Comment: Having said that this is a duplicate question, I'd also agree with the answerer of that question that it is a technical and not particularly enlightening reason.  It's not a ridiculous question, but it's not how you will typically think about continuity at least until you get to topology or real analysis.  Is there a specific reason why this question occurred to you?

Comment: Note also  that "smooth" is a somewhat fuzzy term. However, it definitely involves differentiability. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472148. Many authors use it to denote a function which has derivatives of all orders. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thanks for your response! The motivation behind the question is just to convince myself that, in some cases, the formal definition violates my “intuition” about continuous functions.